# Using GPS in android application

Tags: android

I am currently working on using GPS in android application. In android docs I saw the following line

```
LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER; 

// Or, use GPS location data: 

// LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

but LocationProvider is an abstract class how come we instantiate LocationProvider, also the 
first line returns a String to the object locationProvider. Can anyone clear my doubt whether 
document is wrong or this involves some other explanation

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody seems to answer what you are asking, and everybody seems to be throwing answers about how to get the location I will interfere.

I had the same question you had when I saw the documentation. The following line:

```
LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
```

Was perhaps intended to be:

```
LocationProvider locationProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Since LocationProvider is an abstract class, this means you have received an instance of a class that sublcases locationProvider, hence you are guaranteed to be able to call the methods defined in the LocationProvider docs.

So, it was just something that was not propperly written, or perhaps intented to avoid copy & paste programming.

Answer (score 1):

To instantiate a LocationManager, there are 2 choices :

1. Create a class extending LocationProvider and implementing all abstract methods
2. Get an instance using LocationManager.getProvider (which will return an instance of a class extending LocationManager)

In the case of #2:
You first need to get an instance of LocationManager using  [Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29).

Then get the LocationProvider instance using [LocationManager.getProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProvider%28java.lang.String%29).

```
final LocationManager locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
final LocationProvider locationProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: I can get what you have given but how can we instantiate LocationProvider we can only inherit abstract class can you say how we can instantiate abstract class?

Answer (score -1):

```
private static LocationListener mGpsListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        /// important stuff goes here
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) { }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) { }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) { }
};

private static LocationListener mNetworkListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        /// important stuff goes here
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) { }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) { }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) { }
};
```

and somewhere initialize the thing:

```
lm = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mGpsListener);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mNetworkListener);
```

Comment: can anyone please see the question properly I am asking whether can we instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: See the docs at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html, you provide a string constant that indicates the provider you want to use. To get the provider object (which is instantiated not by you but by the API) use `LocationManager.getProvider(String name);`. Just read the ... manual.